# Running android SDK in lighetest way

Tags: android, performance

I tried Andorid SDK to run and implement on my system using various source. But all of them make heavy load and my system start responsind very slow and get hanged once i start creating app using eclipes

Config: 1gb RAM, core2duo processor, 2.0 Ghz 32bit

Is there any link/reference/tips to SDK which runs in lighter way with above config?

Comment: this is what i do,open task manager after the emulator starts then right click on the emulator->go to process->right click->set affinity->set priority high

Comment: @ViVekH: thanks dude, which source files do you use?